# Reduce CSV upload time for big csv files

Tags: magento-1.9, csv

I am working on a custom module where I want to upload a csv file in the admin backend. The csv would have a minimum of 150000 entries and it is right now taking more than 2 hours to complete the import

Comment: better to  go with the magmi ?

Comment: There isn't much you can do, objects are rather big in Magento. If we're talking products then 150k is quite a big number. Unless you want to manually query the DB it won't be any faster.

Comment: you can use direct sql query using transaction object, rollback.

Answer (score 0):

**direct SQL queries is the only option, ugly but fast (refer to magmi project for implementation)**

sample code:

```
$file = 'file.csv';
$csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
$data = $csv->getData($csv);
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
foreach($data as $row){
  $value1 = $row[1];
  $write->query("INSERT INTO table(value1) VALUES('{$value1}')");
}
```